# Is it possible to read only first N bytes from the HTTP server using Linux command?

Tags: linux, http, url, command

Given the url *http://www.example.com*, can we read the first N bytes out of the page?

- using **wget**, we can download the whole page.
- using **curl**, there is -r, 0-499 specifies the first 500 bytes. Seems solve the problem.

  > You should also be aware that many HTTP/1.1 servers do not have this feature enabled, so that when you attempt to get a range, you'll instead get the whole document.
- using **urlib** in Python. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986392/what-is-the-best-way-to-open-a-url-and-get-up-to-x-bytes-in-python), but according to Konstantin's comment, is that really true?

  > Last time I tried this technique it failed because it was actually impossible to read from the HTTP server only specified amount of data, i.e. you implicitly read all HTTP response and only then read first N bytes out of it. So at the end you ended up downloading the whole 1Gb malicious response.

So, how can we read the first N bytes from the HTTP server in practice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
curl <url> | head -c 499
```

or

```
curl <url> | dd bs=1 count=499
```

should do

Also there are simpler utils with perhaps borader availability like

```
    netcat host 80 <<"HERE" | dd count=499 of=output.fragment
GET /urlpath/query?string=more&bloddy=stuff

HERE
```

Or

```
GET /urlpath/query?string=more&bloddy=stuff
```

Comment: Thanks. Using *curl* or *GET*, we can get the whole document. So with *dd* or *head*, we can cut the length. But is it possible we don't need to get the whole page?

Comment: Streaming. UNIX philosphy and pipes: they are data streams. Since curl and GET are unix filters, ending the receiving pipe (dd) will terminate curl or GET early (SIGPIPE). There is no telling whether the server will be smart enough to stop transmission. However on a TCP level I suppose it would stop retrying packets once there is no more response.

Comment: If the file is binary, you'll probably want to use dd. The dd command defaults to a blocksize of 512 bytes, so if you only want the first 499 bytes, you need to do 'dd bs=1 count=499'. Or if you only want the first 512 bytes, 'dd count=1' will do.

Answer (score 34):

You can do it natively by the following curl command (no need to download the whole document).  According to the curl man page:

> RANGES
> HTTP 1.1 introduced byte-ranges. Using this, a client can request   to get only one or more subparts of a specified document. `curl`
> supports this with the `-r` flag.
>
> ```
> Get the first 100 bytes of a document:
>     curl -r 0-99 http://www.get.this/
>
> Get the last 500 bytes of a document:  
>     curl -r -500 http://www.get.this/
>
> `curl` also supports simple ranges for FTP files as well.
> Then you can only specify start and stop position.
>
> Get the first 100 bytes of a document using FTP:
>     curl -r 0-99 ftp://www.get.this/README
> ```

It works for me even with a Java web app deployed to GigaSpaces.

Comment: Note that the server has to support this option

Answer (score 2):

> You should also be aware that many
>   HTTP/1.1 servers do not have this
>   feature enabled, so that when you
>   attempt to get a range, you'll instead
>   get the whole document.

You will have to get the whole web anyways, so you can get the web with curl and pipe it to head, for example.

> head
>
> c, --bytes=[-]N
>       print the first N bytes of each file; with the leading '-', print all
>   but the last N bytes of each file

Comment: Now, I am using curl | head. Is there any commands that don't download the whole web page, just give the first N bytes? thx.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a way to time the server's processing time, which I thought I could measure by telling curl to stop downloading after 1 byte or something.

For me, the better solution turned out to be to do a HEAD request, since this usually lets the server process the request as normal but does not return any response body:

```
time curl --head <URL>
```

Comment: Many servers, e.g. Amazon S3, explicitly disable `HEAD` requests.

Answer (score -1):

Make a socket connection. Read the bytes you want. Close, and you're done.

Comment: Yes, you are right, @adymitruk. But if not socket, there is no linux command can handle these needs?