# Get a part of the sourcecode of a Website in unix

Tags: unix, debian, wget

How can I get just a specific part of the source code of a website without having to get the whole document with wget and then grep?  I only need a small part and getting the whole source code causes a lot traffic.

Is there a possibility to stop reading the source code when I got the part I want? I just need the first few lines...

Comment: holes causing traffic? like potholes?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787213/is-it-possible-to-read-only-first-n-bytes-from-the-http-server-using-linux-comma

Answer (score 0):

You can add a call to `head` in your pipeline, to keep only lines at the head of the output.